# Joomla component parameters

Tags: joomla

How to create serialized parameter?

i.e. I have one or more depositfiles link, different for each article.
Also there are perhaps other fileshare services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version of Joomla you're using, so answering for 1.5+

**Joomla 1.6/1.7**

One option is to use a text field type. See a list of all the types available to you here:
http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

However, it is possible to create your own custom field type with a better user interface. Say, a text box with a '+' button that gives you more text boxes for links as needed, but saves in a similar manner to the above. This works the same as custom field types in a component - see here for a tutorial:
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_modal_form_field_in_1.6/1.7

**Joomla 1.5**

Use a text parameter type. See a list of all the types available to you here:
http://docs.joomla.org/Parameter